# How to Insert data into Wordpress database table?

Tags: database, wordpress, insert

I'm very new in PHP and WordPress. Actually I'm learning now so I hope that I will find support on my journey in this community. :)

Now, I try to insert data from a form into WordPress database using MVC model but it is not working.

The thing is that it doesn't return any error, nor in console or in browser, so I can't figure out what's happening...

In the code below I used GET method but I also tried with POST but same result.

I'm aware that the query must be sanitized but first I want to see that it works.

```php
class BitTestModel2{
    private $brand;
    private $cod;
    private $cantitate;
    private $db_conn;

    public function __construct($a,$b,$c,$d) {
        $this->brand =$a;
        $this->cod = $b;
        $this->cantitate=$c;
        $this->db_conn = $d;
    }

    public function send_data() {
        
        if (empty($this->cantitate)) {

            echo 'Please insert data';
        
        } else{

            for ($index = 0; $index < count($this->cantitate); $index++) {

                $f_brand = $this->brand[$index];    
                $f_cod = $this->cod[$index];
                $f_cantitati = $this->cantitate[$index];

                if (!empty($f_cantitati)) {

                    $table = $this->db_conn->prefix. 'date_abg';

                    var_dump($table);

                    echo '<br><br>';

                    $param = array(
                        'brand' => $f_brand,
                        'cod' => $f_cod,
                        'cantitate' => $f_cantitati
                    );

                    print_r( 'Will insert the line ::');
                    echo '<br><br>';
                    var_dump($param);

                    $stm =$this->db_conn -> insert($table, $param);
                    echo '<br><br>';
                    var_dump($stm);
                    echo '<br><br>';
                }
            }

            $noticemsg = "";

            if (!empty($param)) {
                echo 'data saved';
            } elseif (empty($param)) {
                $noticemsg .= 'please insert data';
                echo $noticemsg;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```php
function bittest_colect_data(){
    global $wpdb;

    require_once('inc/model.php');

    require_once('inc/view.php');

    $brand = isset($_GET['brand']) ?$_GET['brand'] : false;
    $cod =  isset($_GET['cod']) ?$_GET['cod'] : false;;
    $cantitate =  isset($_GET['cantitate']) ?$_GET['cantitate'] : false;
    var_dump($cantitate);

    $model_obj = new BitTestModel( $wpdb);
    $results = $model_obj->get_table();

    $model_obj2 = new BitTestModel2($brand, $cod, $cantitate , $wpdb);
    $model_obj2->send_data();

    $view_obj = new BitTestView;
    $output = $view_obj->show_table($results);
    
    return $output;
    
}
```

Comment: Are the various `var_dump()` calls in `send_data()` being executed at all? You could also try replacing them with `error_log( print_r(VARIABLE_HERE, true) );` and see if anything is being written to [debug.log](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/).

Comment: the ```var_dump($stm); ``` return bool(false) .   error_log( print_r(VARIABLE_HERE, true) ); doesn't return anything in debug.log.  the  all other ```var_dump( )``` return what it should

Comment: Alright, did you check that: a) the database table exists, b) the database table name is correct, and c) that the column names are correct?

Comment: all above checked. Also the ```var_dump ($param);``` return the right array that should be inserted in database table....

Comment: Try this: add `$this->db_conn->show_errors();` right before the `insert(...)` line, then add `$this->db_conn->print_error();` after the `insert(...)` line and see if that shows any error messages.

Comment: so, I found something that seems weird for me: I have two tables - Table A where I keep initial data that I call in view, and Table B where I intend to send my data along with user input. Initially I imported my data in Table A from a CSV file. Now I added some rows with sql statements directly from workbench and those fields added with sql statement can be inserted in wordpress data base but only with GET method :(

Comment: this is the error for rows with values added from CSV file : SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wp_date_abg`. for those added from workbench :WordPress database error: []
INSERT INTO `wp_date_abg` (`brand`, `cod`, `cantitate`) VALUES (' Arctic', ' ARG', '5')

Answer (score 0):

When working with WordPress database, there is already the `wpdb` class, which you need to use for all your database operations.

This link below should give you all the details on how to use it:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/

Comment: OP __is__ using the `wpdb` class. See `$model_obj2` in `bittest_colect_data()`.